# Show 'page not found' on Drupal 7 node page

Tags: drupal-7, http-status-code-404

Need show 404 page on node page when some condition is true. I know that Drupal have drupal_not_found(), but I don't know where to use it. If I use it in hook_init() some blocks is not displaying. Where to use it function of maybe there is another solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried using the [hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) ?
Watch for the "view_mode" parameter also.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Think about this solution today and you confirmed my supposition. I know "view_mode" param, it can help to not use drupal_not_found()? Or jsut to determine node view type?) Thanks anyway!)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into https://www.drupal.org/project/context_error
It is just an additional module for Context (https://www.drupal.org/project/context) specifically for 404 and/or 403 pages. Context allows you to define conditions and display blocks/views/menus/etc based on those contexts.

Comment: Interesting, can I programmatically add some conditions by this module?